# Use pivot to get sum of each column using a join

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL and I want to first join them and then use a pivot and get sum for each column by date.

For example:

Table Name Sales:

[image]

I have another Table called Manufacturer:

[image]

I want to join these tables and sum up the totals for Offer_Price, Sale_Price and Discount. I want to get the results date wise for each Manufacturer.

I wrote a query:

```
*/
Select Manufacturer_Name ,
    date,
    Offer_Price,
    Sale_Price,
    Discount
From
(
    Select M.name, S.Date,  S.Offer_Price, S.Sale_Price , S.Discount
    from dbo.sales S
    Inner join dbo.Manufacturer M on S.m_id = M.M_id
) as PivotData
Pivot (Sum(Offer_Price) , sum (Sale_Price), sum (Discount)
For date in ([2020-03-22], [2020-03-21], [2020-03-20])) as pivoting /*
```

But I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

This error is for the row where I am adding up the columns.

I am trying to learn pivot but I am stuck here. Can someone help?

Please note that I made up the data above, these are not the actual columns and tables but they are similar.

The results I want are like:

For Manufacturer Vivo and date 03/22/2020 it should add up and show offer price as 20,000, sale_Price as 19900, discount as 100 in a single row.

Comment: You can only aggregate 1 column when pivoting so `Sum(Offer_Price), sum (Sale_Price), sum (Discount)` is throwing an error on the comma because you are trying to aggregate 3 times.

Comment: BTW - please put the results back as text, text is by far the preferred option not images. And I had formatted it all neatly for you (just using the `{}` code formatting option).

Comment: Thanks for replying Dale! Is there another way to get a sum of each column? Although I was trying to learn Pivot, are you saying pivoting wont work in my case?

Comment: I tried putting text, and it wasn't formatted properly and I thought I'll get brickbats for it, so I edited it and added image. Sorry!

Comment: Google "pivot multiple columns"

Comment: You format data the same as your format code - easy :)

Comment: Btw - those were not results, the text was the data in each table.

Comment: I will search using the search string you mentioned. I tried searching with the following strings:- "sql pivot with inner join and sum multiple columns" and 
"sql syntax sum multiple columns" but not much luck.  Also, I am new here, sorry for the mistakes.